# Subclassing TDataset: InternalRefresh

Tags: database, delphi

What are you supposed to do in InternalRefresh when you subclassing TDataset in Delphi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the data from the database again. The public interface to this is `TDataSet.Refresh`.

Note that `TQuery`'s override of this just throws an exception. There's not a strict requirement to do anything useful here, if you don't care about supporting `Refresh`.